# How to open RJ11 cash drawer in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, pos

I have a cash drawer (Model = PSHOP CD4141) and POS PC (Posbank Apexa G). I can open cash drawer via XPrinter Q900 after or before printing receipt (there is an option in printer settings). But i need to open drawer without printer. There are RJ11 ports on the POS PC. I tried this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.PointOfService;

namespace POS
{
    public class CashDrawerClass
    {
        CashDrawer myCashDrawer;
        PosExplorer explorer;

        public CashDrawerClass()
        {
            explorer = new PosExplorer(this);
            DeviceInfo ObjDevicesInfo = explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer");
            myCashDrawer = explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo);
        }

        public void OpenCashDrawer()
        {
            myCashDrawer.Open();
            myCashDrawer.Claim(1000);
            myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = true;
            myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
            myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = false;
            myCashDrawer.Release();
            myCashDrawer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest how can i open cash drawer without printer?

Comment: According to pages 5-6 of [the manual](http://usa.posbank.com/resources/down.php4?board_idx=541&Bcode=manual), it seems that RJ11 connector is COM4 for VFD and CashDrawer is RJ45 connector for selective replacement with COM5. And it seems that it is necessary to select factory options to use it for CashDrawer. Isn't it possible to select after shipping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. As @kunif said, Apexa G comminucates with cash drawer on COM5 port. All i need simple Write() command. Following code works:

```
string port = "COM5";    
using (SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(port))
{
     serialPort.Close();
     serialPort.Open();
     serialPort.Write("\x001B@\x001Bp\0.}");
     serialPort.Close();
}
```